# Play a video before it finish to download

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app i download an video from the web and i want to play will it downloaded.

I am using :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data;
```

to save the data i get to a file with:

```
    if (currentBytes == 0) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1"]];
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:fileName contents:data attributes:nil];
        handle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:fileName] retain];
        [handle seekToEndOfFile];
    }else {
        if (!data) {
            NSLog(@"");
        }
        [handle writeData:data];
    }
    currentBytes++;
```

and then when i got to 50% from the video that was downloaded i want to start play it with AVPlayer :

```
if ((percentComplete > 50)&&(flag == NO)) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.mp4", [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1"]];

    audioPlayer = [[AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]] retain];
    avPlayerLayer = [[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:audioPlayer] retain];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];

    [audioPlayer play];

    [[self.view layer] addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];


    flag = YES;
}
```

any idea why it won't work ?

Comment: Could it be that AvPlayer checks the file before it tats playing? Maybe AvPlayer is expecting something special at the end of the file. - Just Ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't play a video like that. if you are downloading the way you do , you need to wait until finish.

if we think about the way you want , you are talking about streaming a video to your application. so to do that here's an example : http://geobray.com/2010/03/26/live-tv-streaming-to-iphone-with-http/

and it shows how to create streaming files i guess.

hope this helps..